# Shiny download function does not actually download a file

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a .csv export function in myt shiny application. Therefore Im following this tutorial:https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html

Everything seems to work fine. Only when I get pop up and try to save the data the screen closes and the file does not show up in the relevant folder.

Does anybody experience the same problem? And could be causing this?

Its just an example shiny package im using:

```
library(shiny)
runExample("10_download")
```

Comment: You'll probably have to show the code you're using.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, it was just running a shiny example. but included it...

Comment: Looks like a bug in the R-Studio interactive shiny application. Note that it works if you open it in the browser - however it does not ask for a directory then, but then saves it directly to the users download directory. Maybe there was some kind of workaround for local use that they broke at some point. I submitted it as a possible bug.

Comment: @MikeWise the immediate download may depend on user's browser settings, not the app.

Comment: Did it work for you? Takes 30 seconds to try out.

Comment: I entered it as a bug on the Shiny site.